# InputStream чтение отрицательных чисел

Tags: java

```
InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(new byte[]{-128, -1, 1, 127});
        while (inputStream.available() > 0){
            int i = inputStream.read();
            System.out.println(i);
        }
```

> Вывод:
>
> 128
>
> 255
>
> 1
>
> 127

Почему пропадает минус? Как его вернуть? Может ли read() прочитать -1 и продолжить чтение дальше?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Метод `read` читает `byte` из потока и возвращает его как `int` в диапазоне от `0` до `255`, а `-1` сигнализирует о достижении конца потока:

> Reads the next byte of data from the input stream. The value byte is returned as an int in the range 0 to 255. If no byte is available because the end of the stream has been reached, the value -1 is returned.

А тип `byte` является 8-битным знаковым целым числом с диапазоном допустимых значений от `-128` до `127` (включительно):

> The byte data type is an 8-bit signed two's complement integer. It has a minimum value of -128 and a maximum value of 127 (inclusive).

Для двоичного представления отрицательных чисел используется [дополнительный код](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4).

Таким образом, -128 выводится как 128, а -1 как 255 и необходимо приведение `int` к `byte`:

```
byte b = (byte) inputStream.read();
```

или

```
System.out.println((byte) i);
```

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснение) У меня еще один вопрос. Почему тогда read() возвращает int, а не short? Это же было бы экономичнее для памяти.

Comment: Я, к сожалению, не могу точно сказать. Вероятно, это как-то связано с оптимизацией. К примеру, если говорить о 32-битной системе, то для неё базовым типом является 32-битный тип, коим и является int. Кстати говоря, литерал целого числа в java тоже int.